# A lot of java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream objects/ Same jars loaded multiple times

Tags: java, memory, jar, garbage-collection

I am checking a heap dump of an Tomcat application which tends to crash when it has increased load right after startup. During the crash I observe an increasing number of unsuccessful attempts to perform `full GC` (6GB max heap size, using `CMS`) and `increased thread count` (ranging from 600 to 2000). MAT reports:

```
One instance of "java.lang.ref.Finalizer" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 
5 291 528 160 (94,59%) bytes. The instance is referenced
by org.python.core.ThreadState @ 0x679fba460 , loaded
by "org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @ 0x674d08e88".
The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.ref.Finalizer" loaded
by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
java.lang.ref.Finalizer
org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @ 0x674d08e88
```

Classes and amount of objects refered by `java.lang.ref.Finalizer`:

```
 ...
 302 org.geoserver.platform.resource.FileSystemResourceStore$FileSystemResource$1
 406 java.net.SocksSocketImpl
 1519 java.util.jar.JarFile
 2075 java.util.zip.Deflater
 2086 org.geotools.map.MapContent
 2094 java.util.Timer$1
 2138 org.geoserver.wms.WMSMapContent
 2328 org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader
 2767 sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile
 4106 javax.media.jai.WritableRenderedImageAdapter
 4724 org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer
 5801 java.io.FileInputStream
 8045 java.util.zip.Inflater
24981 java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream
26772 java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream
```

Files reffered by `java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream`:

```
  ...
  339 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/gt-metadata-9.4.jar
  345 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
  388 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/javassist.jar
  396 /usr/local/tomcat8/lib/orai18n-servlet.jar
  427 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
  448 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/xstream-1.4.2.jar
  449 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-core-1.17.jar
  474 /usr/local/tomcat8/lib/orai18n.jar
  538 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-1.17.jar
  553 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/gt-referencing-9.4.jar
  591 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/jts-1.13.jar
  614 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
  679 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/gt-opengis-9.4.jar
  688 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-gml3-15.2.jar
  908 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/jai-core-1.1.3.jar
 1023 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/gt-main-9.4.jar
 1161 /usr/local/tomcat8/webapps/my-server/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar
 1194 /usr/local/tomcat8/lib/orai18n-translation.jar
 1688 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/rt.jar
 6631 /usr/local/tomcat8/lib/ojdbc6.jar
```

It seems strange to me that `jar` files are being loaded multiple times. I would suspect memory leak but since even `jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/rt.jar` is loaded 1000+ times I do not know what to think. **So I am looking for an explanation why Java loads same jar files multiple times**. Maybe there is a flag to control this process and I could improve Tomcat's performance that way.

Answer (score -2):

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212621
the finalize method will be removed in jdk9;
The `finalize` method in `java.util.ZipFile`, `java.util.Inflator`, and `java.util.Deflator` was deprecated for removal in JDK 9 and its implementation was updated to be a no-op.

so if you upgrade to use jdk 9 or above, there will not such issue in jdk 9.

for how to fix in jdk 8, still no idea.

brs

Comment: What does this have to do with this question?  It seems unrelated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @GeneralGrievance The `Finalizer` executes the `finalize()` methods